# auto pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I am curious to know how an auto_ptr is implemented in c++. And i tried to find out where the source of it is located in ubuntu 10.04. I could only find the .h file but couldn't find its implementation. where can i find it?

Comment: Better to look at the implementation of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` (both found in `shared_ptr.h` for gcc 4.4). `auto_ptr` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `auto_ptr` is a template, and the whole code is most likely in the header file.

You can check on libstdc++ 4.4 implementation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01060.html).

Answer (score 7):

The .h file is almost certainly its implementation.  `auto_ptr` is a template.  Since template implementations need to be included in full, they're normally in the .h files.

Comment: if i am really interested to see how an auto_ptr is implemented....what should i do?

Comment: @nikhil: Read the .h file. On my system (still 9.10) it's /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/auto_ptr.h, or use the link icecrime gave.

Answer (score 0):

It is a template class, so the details are exposed in the header file: take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's a template, so it's all in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference to Scott Meyers's [auto_ptr](http://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/auto_ptr-update.html)